# Magnific popup, как задать разный бэкграунд?

Tags: jquery, плагин

Допустим нужно для разных модальных окон задать разный цвет бэкграунда.
По умолчанию для класса .mfp-bg задан основной цвет rgba(0,0,0,.5)
Подскажите, как можно менять цвет класса .mfp-bg в зависимости от открытого модального окна?

Comment: добавить новый класс css  и прописать нужный цвет фона

Comment: @soledar10, класс будет добавляться дважды

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

1. окно с черным фоном
2. окно с красным фоном

```js
$('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
$('.popup-gallery-2').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    },
    callbacks: {
        beforeOpen: function() {
            var $triggerEl = $(this.st.el),
                newClass = $triggerEl.data("modal-class");
            if (newClass) {
                this.st.mainClass = this.st.mainClass + ' ' + newClass;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.white-popup-block {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.mfp-bg-red {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="popup-gallery">
    <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_b.jpg" title="The Cleaner"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
</div>
<div class="popup-gallery-2">
    <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8558295631_0f56c1284f_b.jpg" data-modal-class="mfp-bg-red" title="Winter Dance"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8382/8558295631_0f56c1284f_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
    <a href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_b.jpg" data-modal-class="mfp-bg-red" title="Winter Dance"><img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8242/8558295633_f34a55c1c6_s.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: отлично, благодарю

Comment: кстати ваш код работает, но теперь класс .mfp-bg-red добавляется дважды: .mfp-bg.mfp-bg-red и mfp-wrap.mfp-bg-red, из-за этого цвет может быть вдвойне наложен друг на друга. Как это исправить?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/5k04hhmk/